# PHP to node.js communication

Tags: php, node.js

I am trying to create a notification system very much like the SO one ( the one when receiving a new message ). 
My site is built in PHP and i would like the notifications to occur when data is inserted to the DB from the PHP.

At the top of my head i would just curl the node server passing it some post parameters, is that right way to do?

Are there any good practice (security, performances..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the redis channels. We use this practice for same prupose. Benefits : you can have a lot of node.js servers and they will receive notifications almost a the same time...

Comment: Thanks for you input, you have any usefull links by anychance ? Also i am running php-fpm and nginx, redis would still work ?

Comment: Yep of course. We use nicolas php redis lib and method publish. That's all.

Answer (score 7):

DNode is a good option.

[A short article](http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/) about DNode made by HENRI BERGIUS.

[DNode for PHP](https://github.com/bergie/dnode-php) on GitHub.